# Can someone explain why 2nd person plural is used when speaking to a single person?

Tags: gramática, conjugación, cortesía, voseo

In the following excerpt of the book *El Quijote: para estudiantes de español*, the protagonist, Don Quijote, is addressing a man, but speaks to him using 2nd person plural:

> Entonces vio a un niño atado a un árbol. El niño gritaba mientras un
>   hombre le golpeaba con un palo.
>
> ...
>
> Don Quijote sacó la lanza y apuntando al hombre dijo:
>
> "¡Cobarde¡ ¿**Pegáis** a un niño? ¿**Pegáis** a quien no puede defenderse?
>   **Pelead** conmigo y **sabréis** lo que es pelear con un hombre."

This is the first time I've seen 2nd person plural used to directly address a **single person**.

Can somebody explain this usage?

Comment: Is the old *vos* treatment that congugates like *vosotros*

Comment: Similar (but not the same) to this: _ustedeo_ uses a 3rd person to addres a second person: "¿**Pega** usted a un niño? ¿**Pega** usted a quien no puede defenderse? **Pelee** usted conmigo y **sabrá** lo que es pelear con un hombre." You might find plenty of questions about _ustedeo_ in our site if you either use the search functionality or the tags.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the Middle Ages it was quite common to use *vos* as courtesy pronoun for the second person, and it uses the verb in the 2nd person plural. This also happened in English, where the 2nd person plural (*you*) was also used as courtesy for the singular, instead of *thou*; this became so common that *thou* was relegated altogether as is no longer used.

*El Quijote* was written a bit later, at the beginning of the 17th century; by that time, *vos* was used only in contempt, as Don Quijote does here (the courtesy form was then *vuesa merced*, which later became *usted*). He does the same when addressing Sancho when he is angry at him. Nowadays, this usage remains common in Portugal's Portuguese, where *você* is only used in contempt or addressing an inferior; in Brazil, however, *você* is the usual pronoun for addressing anybody.

Of course, *vos* is still commonly used nowadays in some countries, mainly in the South Cone, but in the form known as *voseo*; this has a special conjugation for the second person, somewhat middle of the road between the singular (*tú*) and plural (*vosotros*) forms.

Comment: Just in case anyone reads *El Quijote* and notices Don Quijote addressing someone respectfully as *vos*: this happens when he believes he is a medieval knight in some castle or a similar situation. In those cases, Don Quijote speaks as such, in an old fashioned way. This is sometimes lost on modern readers because, for us, 17th century Spanish is old fashioned too; but contemporary readers noticed that speech quite easily.